# Isekai manga/manhwa/manhua about a noble boy who's considered weak, and has a stepmother who wants to kill him

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

A few years back, I read an isekai-type manga/manhwa/manhua (most likely a manga, but I'm not sure).

The setting is in the medieval era, I guess. It was about a noble teenage boy who is considered weak (if my memory didn't betray me, he was ill) who has (maybe) two siblings from a different mother.

This stepmother always planned to kill him to prevent him becoming the head of the family. Little did they know, he wasn't sick anymore.

In a fight scene I recalled, this boy unleashes an awesome AOE skill called 'God's Territory'. This and that happened, and I forgot the title of the manga.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this manga mostly in black & white or in full colour?

Comment: @LogicDictates, I'm really sorry. But that detail is lost to me. Oh, one thing comes back to me. The MC seems like familiar with the 'gods' or some kind of 'ancient heroes', he prayed to the gods during the match. But not in a calm and repectful manner, but in a more  brash and carefree way. Perhaps the pray is needed to unleash the God's Territory skill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for The Max Level Hero Has Returned! by 유도.

> The weak prince of an insignificant country, Davey. After becoming comatose, his soul escaped to a temple where the souls of heroes gathered. He trained for a thousand years and has now returned as a max-level hero! “Just you guys wait, I’m gonna face you all head-on!” The refreshing story of Davey’s royal life and revenge has just begun.

> In a fight scene I recalled, this boy unleashes an awesome AOE skill called 'God's Territory'

[image: God's territory]

> He prayed to the gods during the match. But not in a calm and respectful manner, but in a more brash and carefree way

[image: Praying to the gods]

Comment: As soon as I read you response, I searched and opened the aforementioned title. Well, I was overwhelmed by nostalgia, I read it until chapter 30. And, you, my good sir, bow to no one.